# How to get single output from PL/SQL procedure having select statement

Tags: plsql, procedure, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to execute one PL/SQL procedure. I am getting nullpointerexception every time. Might be I am returning the procedure in wrong way.

Can you please help me in this procedure.

```
PROCEDURE p_regidexport(countryid IN varchar2, cropid IN varchar2, productid IN VARCHAR2, pregid out varchar)
IS
 fnc       VARCHAR2(30) := 'P_REGIDEXPORT';
 query     VARCHAR2(10000);
 regid varchar(20);


 BEGIN

select REG_ID into regid from GRS_Registration where LOC_ID =(select loc_id from GRS_location where Country = ' || countryid || ') AND CROP_ID = (select crop_id from GRS_crop where CROP_NM = ' || cropid || ')AND REG_NAME =' || '''' || productid || ''';

pregid := regid;
 sub_log('P_REGIDEXPORT:'||pregid);
dbms_output.put_line(pregid);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN no_data_found THEN
dbms_output.put_line('No record present');      


END P_REGIDEXPORT;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null pointer exception" in PL/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need not to concatenate in parameter value. because its not dynamic query. so, you can directly pass the parameter variable into ur query.
make sure that your qry will return one single value.

its just idea based upon ur code, u can try based upon ur requirement.
Hope it will help you!!

```
   create or replace  PROCEDURE p_regidexport(countryid IN varchar2, cropid IN varchar2, productid IN VARCHAR2, pregid out varchar)
    IS
    fnc       VARCHAR2(30) := 'P_REGIDEXPORT';
    query     VARCHAR2(10000);
    regid varchar(20);

    BEGIN
        begin
          select nvl(REG_ID,'0') into regid from GRS_Registration 
          where 
          LOC_ID =(select loc_id from GRS_location where Country = countryid ) AND 
          CROP_ID = (select crop_id from GRS_crop where CROP_NM =  cropid)AND 
          REG_NAME = productid ;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
                  dbms_output.put_line('No record ');  --- or regid  ='0';  
        end;
        pregid := regid;
        --sub_log('P_REGIDEXPORT:'||pregid);
        dbms_output.put_line(pregid);
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('No record present' || ' - ' || sqlerrm);      
    END P_REGIDEXPORT;
```

All the best!! if it is useful click up button which is in left side of this answer

Comment: Actually, values of countryid, cropid and productid are coming from web application and using those values I need to return single output from it

Comment: what ever it might be came... but you will pass those parameter value into this procedure rite? (this is for my understanding) then you want to create procedure to get **regid** as output from this proc?  or u want access this procedure to get tht out parameter value !! what is ur requirement?

Comment: Yeah!, requirement is that only, But these values are string so we need to concatenate them. If I am wrong please correct me

Comment: what ever it is.. no problem.. ur not directly hard coded into ur qry. parameter value should assign it to qry so u need not to concatenate , jst try my code if any issues let me know, i ll help you to solve it.

Comment: Thanks alot, it is working for me. You saved to much time of mine. If you don't mind can I ask one thing. What is the problem in the query that I made. Can't we use that in that way that I was using. because earlier it was working for me. suddenly it stopped. Can you please check my query and let me knw what is the issue in it.

Comment: might be ur ('')quotes is the problem, but one thing, if you use parameter value you should not given with in ('') quotes. if u give it as like that oracle will understating as string(hard coded). **if it is useful click up button which is in left side of this answer**

Comment: This question is helpful in understand basic things. If you think the same, do vote the post.

Comment: yaeh!! all the best